# Convert Array of Objects to flat object without title names

Tags: javascript

What I currently have is structure like this:

[image]

What I actually trying to accomplish is structre like this:
(no title names, just plain values seperated by ,)

```
{
  "1082" : "Karlshamn",
  "1080" : "Karlskrona",
  "1060" : "Olofström", ........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
let map = [];
list.forEach(el => map[el.id] = el.text);
```

Comment: Good exactly what i was looking for! Thanks